# TypeError: Failed to fetch API . react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I got a typeerror while trying to render the website contents in my App

```
import React ,{useState,useEffect} from "react";
import { FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function Home(){
    const [data,setData]= useState([{}]);
    useEffect(()=>{
        fetch('https://corona.askbhunte.com/api/v1/data/nepal')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data)=> setData(data))
        .catch((error) => alert(error));
    },[])
    
    return(
        
        <View> 
           <FlatList
          data={data}
          keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Text>{item.tested_positive}</Text>
          )}
        />
          
        </View>
    )
}
```

I want to fetch data from a website in my app.
The screen renders but it does not fetch any data.

Comment: And what is the error? Can you update your question to include the full error message and any accompanying stacktrace?

Comment: it says: TypeError: Failed to fetch. the home screen renders. but it does not show any data

Comment: So I guess you investigate why it failed to fetch? What do you find when you check the network tab in the browser's dev tools for this GET request?

Comment: The response from "https://corona.askbhunte.com/api/v1/data/nepal" is an object, not an array, and I see no nested array data either.

Comment: the api response is in json format and its not an array. so you really don't need a flatlist to render it (pretty sure you can't render objects with flatlist). try `<Text>{item.tested_positive}</Text>`.

Comment: @saeedghotb `<Text>{data.tested_positive}</Text>` 

Answer (score 1):

I suspect because of the quasi-initialized state that and error is thrown on the initial render when `item.tested_positive` is attempted to be render from an empty object (`{}`).

It turns out that the response isn't even an array, it's an object.

```
{
  "tested_positive": 274869,
  "tested_negative": 1925081,
  "tested_total": 2199950,
  "in_isolation": 870,
  "quarantined": 56,
  "tested_rdt": 312402,
  "pending_result": 0,
  "recovered": 270987,
  "deaths": 3012,
  "source": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jt0EU0mrmfHK9k5gzgKxgD5VdMpXAVRO/view",
  "updated_at": "2021-03-09T00:00:00.000Z",
  "latest_sit_report": {
    "type": "MOHP",
    "_id": "5f8ec6b9b086da747e3e7ce9",
    "no": 253,
    "date": "2020-10-19",
    "url": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jt0EU0mrmfHK9k5gzgKxgD5VdMpXAVRO/view",
    "created_at": "2020-10-20T11:15:05.888Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-10-20T11:15:05.888Z",
    "__v": 0
  }
}
```

Fix the initial state and render the `data` directly.

```
export default function Home() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({}); // <-- just an object
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://corona.askbhunte.com/api/v1/data/nepal')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data)=> setData(data))
      .catch((error) => alert(error));
  },[])
    
  return(
    <View> 
      <Text>{data.tested_positive}</Text> // <-- render from data
    </View>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit typeerror-failed-to-fetch-api-react-native]

Comment: thanks but are there any cons of rendering data directly instead of using an array?

Comment: @arpandhakal Cons, none I can think of. It's more work to pack the non-array data into an array and then map it. It's rather pointless if there's only one "element" to save, access, and render.